# How to configure Boost with Netbeans 6.9 on Ubuntu

Tags: regex, linux, configuration, boost, netbeans

I have gcc 4.4.5 and the latest boost library. I want to use boost specifically for its regex library. I tried using the built in c++ regex functions but apparently they are not fully functional yet. I followed a tutorial online to set up netbeans.

I added /usr/include/boost to the c++ code assistance include directories. I then added -lboost_regex-mt to the build>linker>additional options area in the project configuration. but I still get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the command thats being created by netbeans:

```
g++ -lboost_regex-mt -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/examples01 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o
```

I also tried doing it with -lboost-regex and -lboost-regex-st and the same error, with only the mt changed.
I also tried running a file using regex objects through the terminal but still got the same error. Can anyone help with this problem? Or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set your project's "Additional Library Directories" so that it knows what other directories to look into for your libraries to link against.

Here's a screenshot from Netbeans' site here: http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/c++/

[image]

edit: note that this will affect the generated compiler command to have `-L` options which specify additional locations to look for library files.

Comment: that changes the compile command to g++ -lboost_regex-mt -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/examples01 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/include/boost  which still produces the same error. Did I do it correctly? I added /usr/include/boost in the additional library directories area

Comment: @Robert - `/usr/include/boost` are probably the `.hpp` header files. You need to set it to the 'lib' directory where all of boost's compiler libraries were installed. Where they are depends on what you did to install. The might be in `/usr/lib/boost` or `/usr/local/lib` or something like that. How did you install Boost on your system?

Comment: I installed it with: sudo apt-get install bcp

Comment: actually that didnt work so i did this: sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-doc

Comment: @Robert - `libboost-dev` suggests a bunch of additional packages, like `libboost-regex-dev`, but I don't know if it will actually install all of those unless you modify apt's settings. Can you try doing a `sudo apt-get install libboost-regex-dev`?

Comment: I cant find boost's compiler libraries in the locations you suggested.

Comment: I installed a ton of random boost packages and its working now, I must have done something wrong with my initial install. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell g++ where to find the libraries. One way doing this is to append the location of boost's libraries to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Note that this is not the same as the header files (the `.hpp` files in the `include` directory) which you said you've already included in your project.

Comment: How would I do that? This would be a gcc problem correct?  Netbeans is configured correctly, its just that I have to change the settings for the compiler?