# Setting up environment for C++/Boost libs (netbeans or eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, netbeans

I've followed so many tutorials now and I can't get this basic, fundamental thing right.
I'm getting started with C++ and moving on from the standard intro stuff (after two books) and I'm working through "Beyond the C++ Standard Library ~ An Introduction to Boost" but I can't seem to get either Netbeans or Eclipse to compile and run my boost projects.

I've looked at [How to configure Boost with Netbeans 6.9 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293371/how-to-configure-boost-with-netbeans-6-9-on-ubuntu)
http://www.fischerlaender.net/development/using-boost-c-libraries-with-gcc-g-under-windows
and a few others but I can't seem to get it right.
In Netbeans (my preference) I've gotten as far as specifying the additional include directories, and netbeans recognizes it to the extent where it provides auto completion when including anything from boost/* e.g #include  is fine but when I try to compile it I get:

```
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:7:27: fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Courtney/Documents/Projects/Desktop/HelloBoost'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Courtney/Documents/Projects/Desktop/HelloBoost'
```

but I don't get why the file cannot be found... any help is much appreciated.
**UPDATE**
Set the include directory under Properties->C++ Compiler and chosen 32 bits as the architecture. The compile error's changed to :

```
"/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Courtney/Documents/Projects/Desktop/HelloBoost'
"/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/helloboost.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Courtney/Documents/Projects/Desktop/HelloBoost'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe -m32   -c -g -I/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/boost/boost_1_46_1 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++.exe -m32    -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/helloboost build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o  
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `cpp_regex_traits_char_layer':
c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:366: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/regex_raw_buffer.hpp:131: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::resize(unsigned int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `save_state_init':
c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:107: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `~save_state_init':
c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:115: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:206: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:1117: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/pattern_except.hpp:75: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:219: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_parser.hpp:218: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:795: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:796: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:795: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:877: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:878: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:877: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:795: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:877: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Courtney/Documents/Projects/Desktop/HelloBoost'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:942: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Courtney/Documents/Projects/Desktop/HelloBoost'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:943: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:942: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:942: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1133: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1134: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1133: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:1133: undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:213: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:442: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:444: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex_creator.hpp:320: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::insert(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/pending/object_cache.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:625: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::lookup_default_collate_name(std::string const&)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:667: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:682: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1051: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1051: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:c:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_46_1/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:1051: undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/helloboost.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 31s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g++.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
```

That compilation command does not have necessary `-I` switch. It seems like the include directory was set in a wrong place. Maybe it was only set for autocompletion, but not compilation?

Comment: Where do I add the include directory? I've tried under Properties -> C++ , under Linker and under Tools->Libs->C++

Comment: It should be something related to the Compiler, not the Linker. I'm really sorry I don't use NetBeans. Here're what I found: To provide necessary include directories, right click on the project icon and select properties. From the Categories box, select C/C++, C compiler, general node. Click on the button near Include Directories. Add necessary paths to the include directories. See if that helps you.

Comment: It's okay, thanks for the response. I've done that before and it didn't work. Tried again and still doesn't. What IDE do you use, if you don't midn me asking, or which one would you recommend for work with boost.

Comment: I used Eclipse CDT. Then I switched to Microsoft Visual C++ Express. And now I'm with Qt Creator. On Windows, you won't go wrong with MS Visual C++ (Express or not).

Comment: Thanks for the response again. I've switched to Ubuntu, will make my life easier. Dual booting with Win7... Installed boost and netbeans and  presto, already playing with some of the libs. thanks again